# Probability (sitting around a circular table )

Tags: probability

A question from an ACT Math test:

> Kenji and Mary are members of a school committee that will be meeting this afternoon. The 6 members of the committee will be seated randomly around a circular table. What is the probability that Kenji and Mary will NOT sit next to each other at the meeting?
> F.1/5;
> G.1/3;
> H.2/5;
> J.3/5;
> K.4/5;

I feel there are cases where some probabilities are overlapping, but I can not tell exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Seat Kenji.  It does not matter where since we only care about the relative positions of Kenji and Mary. Once Kenji has been seated, in how many places could Mary sit?  Of these places, how many of them are not next to Kenji?

Answer (score 0):

Total number of members to be seated around the table, N = 6.
Assuming that Kenji is already seated, it means that, all options left for Mary to sit is N-1, 6-1 = 5.

The total possible ways Mary and Kenji can possibly seat, such that they seat next to each other is 2.

Therefore, the probability P, they seat next to each other would be equal to: The number of possible way the two friends would seat such that they are next to each other (2) divided by the All possible ways they can seat (5).

That is, P= 2/5.

Therefore probability that they do not seat next to each other would be 1-P. i.e 1-2/5, and this would give you 3/5.